# How to get Laravel SignedRoute to work with HTTPS

Tags: laravel

When I check the signed route it is always coming back as false. I've read through the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls) and implemented the code but it still fails. I'm allowing the user to download a file. Heres my blade code to display the url:

```
<a href="{{ URL::temporarySignedRoute('files.download', now()->addMinutes(30), $file, false) }}" class="text-indigo-500"></a>
```

In my AppServiceProvider boot method I have

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Then in my controller

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function download(Request $request, File $file)
    {
        abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 401);
        return Storage::download($file->path, $file->filename);
    }
}
```

Everytime I create a url and then go to the url I get an abort 401